# JavaScript: how to trigger update form after setting input

Tags: kendo-ui

I am writing a simple App Inventor program to populate a [Covid-19 school health check page](https://healthscreening.schools.nyc/?type=G).  I am stuck on selecting a school.  Normally you type in a school name, the page finds string matches and you select from the list of string matched school.  I am able to simply set the field manually but the rest of the form doesn't update.  I know I must trigger an update but I cannot make head or tails of how this page works.

[image of school selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8RWu.png)

[typing in part of school name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95nIH.png)

From the Chrome console I can do the following:

```js
x = document.getElementsByClassName("k-textbox")
x[1].value = "Horace"
```

From the picture you can see the text was updated to "Horace" but the results have not updated.  What should I do to force an update so the results list shows proper matches?  Also, how do I query the matching results so I can confirm that my input was explicit enough to return a single match?  FYI, this form entry page will be hidden to the user.

Comment: Your question is confusing. What do you mean by "the rest of the form doesn't update"? After picking a School, you want the Floor to be populated? Can you provide a minimal, reproducible, and working example of your problem? Your Kendo Dropdown seems to be behaving as it should be.

Comment: The purpose of the box is to enter a partial school name and then select from the a small filtered list the actual school name.

My code just hard codes the value but the filtered results doesn't get updated.   I suspect I need to tell the form that the form has actually changed even though there were no key press events.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the kendoDropDownList, call the read method from it's dataSource, and pass the `locationName` value of what you want. This won't set the text in the textbox, but it will filter your list down like you want.

To test, click on the input, open your console, and run the following:

```js
$('#Location').data('kendoDropDownList').dataSource.read({ locationName: 'horace' })
```